# Disable sign-up in runtime (Angular + NestJS)

Tags: angular, api, rest, web-services, nestjs

I'm developing a back-end (NestJS) and front-end (Angular) that, after the installation (no user in the database), it allows the adminitrator to sign up through the sign-up form. After the sign-up of the administrator, the application shall not allow other users to sign up, only by invitation from the administrator.

I'm struggaling to figure out how the Angular app identifies, in runtime, that the sign-up is disabled, and doesn't render the sign-up form.

I thought in 1) the Angular app to do an HTTP `OPTIONS` request to `/signup` and the back-end returns `200` or `400` if it's enabled or not, but this solution can mess up with requests made by the browser due to CORS. Or, 2) add an endpoint (e.g. `/signup-enabled`) where the Angular app can do a `GET` and can check if the sign-up is enabled or not.

One thing that I didn't like about the two solutions above is to make an HTTP request every time the Angular app starts.

What solution do you suggest to solve this problem? Do you know any other solution?

Comment: What's wrong with making an HTTP request every time the app starts? It's quite common for a client app to get a server side configuration on startup.

Comment: It's not a problem. Do you think adding an endpoint to get the server-side configuration is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Yes I would go with the second option

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a third scenario. I think that if you don't want to show some message saying that form is not enabled because admin is login you can allow that any user can log in and in your backend simple return a `401`, with a special message inside saying the rejected reason, that you can show in your form hint.

In general, I prefer to play with common error codes and already existent endpoints before to create a new one each time that I require a special use case.